# What is the regular expression to match the string after id= in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to match the string after `id=` from the below selenium exception so that I can use it in a ui pop up to tell the user which is the attribute causing error.

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: [id="dragg"]

In this case I am expecting the regex to return dragg

I am not able to create a good regex pattern to match this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want all the chars between double quotes,

```
import re

myStr = """selenium.common.exceptions...... [id="dragg"]"""

print(re.search(r'id=\"([^\"\']*)\"', myStr).group(1))
# dragg
```

Comment: Obviously you didnt test this. (.*) captures all characters including the following "

Comment: @user1363990 Normally `id` shouldn't include double quotes but yes, I will correct my answer.